# popup on case object edit page, when a picklist value is selected

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, picklist, lightning-apps

Is there any way I can have a dialog box pop over on selection of particular picklist in the standard case object.

My use case is: If the user selects one of the picklist value from the dropdown in the case Object, user need to see the popup with the particular information on the dialog box popover.

[image]

**I am trying to display the same thing as in the above screenshot as a popup in case object**

[image]

Comment: Not possible with standard case layout you will have to custom build lightning/aura components to achieve this

Comment: What about instead of a pop up, it displays the popup information under the dropdown? If you don't want to create a custom component, you can have another field or text that displays dependent on the selection of the dropdown in lightning app builder for case object.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed to RedDevil, it is not possible on standard page layout.

You can create a lightning component which you can add on standard page and achieve this functionality in lightning experience.

And for the classic view, You can use iframe to achieve this functionlity.

Comment: Thanks! but I have to show the popup for the specific selection of the picklist value. Could you please suggest how I can implement only for the particular field.

Comment: Create a lightning component which will have the picklist field, on change of picklist value open an modal popup using overlay library. and saving the picklist value on case will be on, onchnage of picklist value.